# Why is this ternary statement giving me a syntax error?

Tags: java

An equivalent if statement works (commented out) , but the ternary operator does not.Why is that ?

```
class Solution {
    public String defangIPaddr(String address) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

        for (char letter : address.toCharArray()) {
            (letter == '.') ? sb.append("[.]") : sb.append(letter); 



            // if (letter == '.')
            //     sb.append("[.]");
            // else 
            //     sb.append(letter);
        }

        return sb.toString(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: You have an assignment, but there's no variable to capture it. Change it like this. `sb.append(letter == '.' ? "[.]" : letter);`

Comment: @RavindraRanwala That sounds more like an _answer_ to me `:-)`

Comment: There are three kinds of "code pieces": statements, expression and statement-expressions (i.e., things usable as both). A single example per kind: `if (...) ...;`, `a ? b : c` and `f(x)` (for non-void `f`).

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent for above code is :

```
sb.append(letter == '.' ? "[.]" : letter);
```

The conditional operator returns a value instead of executing a statement. That is why you got the syntactical error 'Not a statement' there. You should not use '?' as a replacement for 'if' statement if your plan is to execute a statement instead of returning a value.

Comment: And the type of the expression is  `String` or `char`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you completely. But I guess you are asking whether the 'letter == '.' ? "[.]" : letter' statement is evaluating to string or char. StringBuilder's append method takes in String, CharSequence or Object as arguments. In this case, the following method is in action :
    public StringBuilder append(Object obj) {
        return append(String.valueOf(obj));
    }

Comment: The use of the Object overload of StringBuilder.append is probably going to cause unnecessary slowdown relative to just writing out the if/else.